# How to define component name in Vue3 setup tag?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

In the `export default {}` method, there is a `name` property to define the component name, which is useful for the Vue Devtools, but what's the equivalent in the new `<script setup>` syntax?

[image]

Comment: in my vue js environment with `script setup`, the dev tools will show the name of the component. **So no additional naming is necessary**. What version of Vue DevTools are you using? What did you see as the name of your components in your DevTools?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Declaring Additional Options

The `<script setup>` syntax provides the ability to express equivalent functionality of most existing Options API options except for a few:

- `name`
- `inheritAttrs`
- Custom options needed by plugins or libraries

If you need to declare these options, use a separate normal  block with export default:

```html
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'CustomName',
    inheritAttrs: false,
    customOptions: {}
  }
</script>

<script setup>
  // script setup logic
</script>
```

Source: [link](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0040-script-setup.md#declaring-additional-options)

Comment: The [official documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#usage-alongside-normal-script) no longer has `name` listed.  Is this still a requirement?

Comment: @NathanGoings, perhaps when using [Include/Exclude for <KeepAlive>](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/keep-alive.html#include-exclude), the docs mention it as necessary, but I haven’t tested myself if that is the case.

Comment: @NathanGoings it's described on another page: https://vuejs.org/api/options-misc.html#name

Comment: Update from vue site
"Since version 3.2.34, a single-file component using <script setup> will automatically infer its name option based on the filename, removing the need to manually declare the name even when used with <KeepAlive>"

Comment: @ajitweb, when I use version 3.2.45, seems the problem still there. and the solution fix the issue of anonymous component name.

Comment: @ajitweb Unfortunately, the component name issue remains a very real problem. When using the app warning and error handlers (app.config.warnHandler and app.config.errorHandler), the instance parameter does not contain the "name" key otherwise generated by an Options file (version 3.3.8).